# Access to client's localhost from server

Tags: php

**Here is the context :** I need to load heavy files in the Google Earth plugin on a website. I have a php script that build up a path to those files and send it to javascript through ajax. Then, the plugin download the file and build it on earth. This take a long time. I need to speed that up for a public event. The computer can run a web server and have these files on his hard drive.

**So here is my question :** Is there a way for php to check if the client is running a local server and check if it contains a specific file ? Or at least, to execute a php script from this local server ?

Something like :

```
if(is_file('localhost/files/heavy.kmz'))
    $path = 'localhost/files/heavy.kmz';
else
    $path = 'www.randomsite.com/files/heavy.kmz';

return $path
```

Of course, this localhost refers to the wrong server :(.
I guess that if it was possible, there would be security issues. But i ask anyway.

I'm not very used to stackoverflow habits, I hope a didn't do anything wrong.

Kororo.

**Edit :** I will try to clarify a bit.

I know the path of the files on localhost. I need to check if it exist or not in order to send a path or another. If i can find it, i don't have to download it from the server. 
The local webserver is only needed on machine to allow php check of the file.

Comment: If I understand your question. Yes. You can test for the existence of a file on a server but only on the public folder, but I'm not sure this is what you are asking

Comment: @kororo Use relevant path like `__DIR__.'/../filepath/filename.ext'`

Comment: I find your description slightly hard to follow. `localhost` is an alias for current machine: the server's localhost is not the same machine than the client's localhost. But you can of course connect to any computer in the Internet that has an open HTTP port.

Comment: I don't understand how `__DIR__` works. Maybe my example is wrong. The local and remote paths and completely differents.

Answer (score 0):

If the data file is on the same machine, and you can tell where your data file should be *relative* to the script you are using to check it's existence, just use the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (or `dirname(__FILE__)` if your php is ancient) to create the path.

So for example, you have have the directory structure like this:

- files/

  - heavy.kmz
- check.php
- ...

Then inside the `check.php` the following work as expected:

```
if (is_file(__DIR__.'/files/heavy.kmz')) {
    $path = __DIR__.'/files/heavy.kmz';
} else {
    $path = 'www.randomsite.com/files/heavy.kmz';
}
```

Comment: In my case, the script that checks for file existance is run server side :/